# transpiling a circuit in Qiskit results is "configuration() missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: qiskit, programming

I was learing about scheduling. So, to test scheduling for a 2 qubit circuit I tried to run this code but found error

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeAlmaden
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile

qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
backend = FakeAlmaden
new_qc2 = transpile(qc2, backend)
new_qc2.draw()
```

```
TypeError: configuration() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please post the error message as well?

Answer (score 1):

Transpile takes a `Backend` instance, not type. In order words, you are missing the `()` after `FakeAlmaden`:

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeAlmaden
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile

qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
backend = FakeAlmaden()
new_qc2 = transpile(qc2, backend)
new_qc2.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a parenthesis while defining the backend. The following code is working fine .
`from qiskit.test.mock import FakeAlmaden`
`qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)`
`backend = FakeAlmaden()`
`new_qc2 = transpile(qc2, backend)`
`transpiled_qc2.draw()`
I see the output to be - 
[image]

Comment: Ya. I missed the bracket. Thanks